# Is it possible to iterate over a tree and indent the results by level with "reduce()"?

Tags: swift

I have a `Class` for storing a tree and want to make it printable.

```
final class Node<Value> : CustomStringConvertible {
    var value : Value
    private(set) var children : [Node]
    var description: String {
        value as! String + children.reduce("") { $0 + "\n" + $1.description }
    }
//...
}
```

With my code, all levels start at the first column of each line. Is it possible to indent the results by level in this way (e.g. by 2 spaces per level)?

```
1
  1.1
    1.1.1
  1.2
    1.2.1
      1.2.1.1
      1.2.1.2
```

I know how to solve this with some lines of code. I only want to know if it is possible by using `reduce()` or something like that to code it in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with a helper method which takes a “level” parameter and calls itself recursively on each child node with an increased level:

```
private func toString(level: Int) -> String {
    String(repeating: " ", count: level) + "\(value)"
        + children.reduce("") { $0 + "\n" + $1.toString(level: level + 2) }
}
var description: String {
    self.toString(level: 0)
}
```

Comment: It's working fine, thx. I only change a little: `String(repeating: "  "` and `level: level + 1`, because it is a bit confusing to increase `level` by 2